# Sharing editable calendar with Outlook (Exchange) and Hotmail (Live/Outlook.com)

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, calendar, hotmail

I'm using Outlook 2010 at work (Exchange). My account is also synced to my Android phone+tablet. For me there is no other solution than to able to add this new calendar to my Outlook, so that I'm able to see all of my calendars side by side, etc...

My spouse uses Hotmail (Outlook/Live or whatever it is these days). She uses this account with her Windows 8 laptop, iPhone and iPad. She's also able to use Google Calendar if that would make this work...

Is there a way for us to have one calendar that we would both be able to edit on all of our devices?

I've done some googling for the better half of the day without any success - I'm starting to think that this is not even possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Exchange can do this but I don't suppose your work would be happy about you having a second calendar and an extra account for your spouse!

Not sure about Live.com though, I thought Microsoft were going to move it to Office 365 but I don't know what limits they put on it. I would guess that if you both have an account on outlook.com that you both know the password for, it should enable you both to use the calendar.

Comment: Thanks for this. I created a Microsoft account for my self. Therefore we both now have Outlook.com calendars. I shared my Outlook.com calendar with my spouse and added that account to my Outlook and am now able to see our shared calender which we are both able to edit. This rocks!

Comment: Oh, and I needed to install Outlook Hotmail Connector to my Outlook in order to add that Outlook.com account.

Comment: Great, glad you're there. I've always used Google calendars in the past but given recent directions from them, I'm seriously thinking of switching.